Improve/shorten R code for processing spatial objects
I am self-taught in R and would like to improve my coding skills. My codes often contain repetitive commands and produce many individual results. I also often find it difficult to combine them into a result overview at the end. I am sure the code could often be much clearer and shorter.
In my current project I have created buffer zones for which I want to calculate the number of buildings per buffer zone in the first step. In the second step, the buffer zones should then be filtered based on a threshold of the number of buildings within (groups: buffer zones with at least 1500 buildings, buffer zones with at least 1000 buildings, buffer zones with at least 500 buildings). In the third step, I want to calculate the number of schools per filter group per buffer zone. It would be great to have one object with all this information at the end. The aim is to use the resulting dataset to plot the various threshold scenarios and calculate the total number of schools for each scenario.
(Part) of my current code:
library(sf)
library(tidyr)

#count polygons within buffer and add column for counts
buffer3000_summary <- buffer3000 %>%
  dplyr::mutate(counts_threshold = lengths(st_intersects(., shp_BAG)))

#filter the buffers per threshold (count of polygons per buffer 1500,1000,500)
th1500 <- buffer3000_summary %>% dplyr::filter(counts_threshold <=1500)
th1000 <- buffer3000_summary %>% dplyr::filter(counts_threshold <=1000)
th500 <- buffer3000_summary %>% dplyr::filter(counts_threshold <=500)

#count the filtered polygons within buffers for filtered buffers
th1500_summary <- th1500 %>%
  dplyr::mutate(counts = lengths(st_intersects(., shp_BAG_slim)))
th1000_summary <- th1000 %>%
  dplyr::mutate(counts = lengths(st_intersects(., shp_BAG_slim)))
th500_summary <- th500 %>%
  dplyr::mutate(counts = lengths(st_intersects(., shp_BAG_slim)))

I would be thankfull for any tip.

One way is to create a list and then use lapply.

If you want to go the tidyverse way, remember that tibbles allows for list columns (i.e., columns in which each element is itself a list). Look into the nest() and nest_by() functions in tidyr.

Find what changes in each iteration (the counts threshold, in your case), and turn your code into a function using it as an argument. Then its easy to repeatedly call that function with different values, especially with lapply, as @Edward suggests.

If you want feedback on working code, try a site like [codereview.se] instead. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions and this doesn't appear to one. At the very least when asking a question here, it's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

There's no need to create separate files in your workflow. Just do buffer3000_summary <- buffer3000 %>% mutate(counts_threshold = lengths(st_intersects(., shp_BAG)), counts = lengths(st_intersects(., shp_BAG_slim))) and then filter() buffer3000_summary for each scenario you want to run e.g. scenario500 <- filter(buffer3000_summary, counts_threshold <= 500) %>% mutate(result = counts_threshold / counts) or whatever you need. You could also create individual buffer objects using filter() if your analyses requires it and this will still save you a bit of time.
